# ActiveAdmin + Mongoid localized fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, activeadmin, mongoid3

I'm using Mongoid as a storage and ActiveAdmin as an admin backend in my Rails project. And I need to support a couple of languages.

Native Rails i18n works perfectly for static texts. But I need also translate db content. I've found that mongoid natively support localized fields: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#localized_fields .

Is there any good way to use ActiveAdmin and this cool feature together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just met the same problem and decided to make a gem for this:

https://github.com/rs-pro/activeadmin-mongoid-localize